# Button onclick doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, dom-events, image-gallery

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am trying to make my own image gallery as my first simple project. I expected it to go smoothly, but it seems like I am doing some trivial mistake, and I have no idea where.

So, my initial plan was: I would set up an image element with empty **src** property, create an array of image names, add a function that will increase the array pointer by 1 any time it is triggered, and then just add the corresponding value in the array to the **src**.

It doesn't work, though. Could you please try to see any errors in the code? I really have no idea what to do, just can't find a mistake.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="" id="imageCanvas">
        <div id="counterDisplay"></div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = ["increased.jpg","knight.jpg","knight-g.jpg","golden.jpg","land.jpg"];

        var counterDisplay = document.getElementById("counterDisplay");
        var imageCanvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
        var imageCount = 0;
        
                // function intended to increase the array position indicator by 1, but it always only increases it in relation to the original imageCount value (0), how to make it save the already increased value?
        function changeCount() {
            imageCount = imageCount+1;
        }
        
        counterDisplay.innerHTML = imageCount;
        imageCanvas.setAttribute("src",images[imageCount]);
            
        </script>
                // The main problem: it just refuses to respond!
        <button onclick="changeCount()">NEXT</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you want is to display the counting???

Answer (score 0):

I didn't debug through this, but my guess is that onclick is being called, but you are not updating the count in that `changeCount` code.

Try putting almost all the code in `changeCount`.

```
function changeCount() {
    imageCount = imageCount+1;
    counterDisplay.innerHTML = imageCount;
    imageCanvas.setAttribute("src",images[imageCount]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function runs when the the button is clicked.

```
function changeCount() {
    imageCount = imageCount+1;
}
```

This code is run when the script first loads.

```
counterDisplay.innerHTML = imageCount;
imageCanvas.setAttribute("src",images[imageCount]);
```

You want it to run when the button is clicked. Move it inside the function.